# Looking for a shorter more effficient way to adding something (potentially) repeating to the end of a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Making a discord bot. So ive got some if statements if the length of an array is a certain value, but im looking if theres an easier more efficient way of doing it, that could work for a theoretical infinite amount of lengths the array could be.

Below is what the if statements are checking the length for

```
        if (sunday.length == 0){
          Embed.addFields({name: 'Sunday', value: `> Nothing`})
        }
        if (sunday.length == 1){
          Embed.addFields({name: 'Sunday', value: `> ${sunday[0].summary}`})
        }
        if (sunday.length == 2){
          Embed.addFields({name: 'Sunday', value: `> ${sunday[0].summary}\n> ${sunday[1].summary}`})
        }
        if (sunday.length == 3){
          Embed.addFields({name: 'Sunday', value: `> ${sunday[0].summary}\n> ${sunday[1].summary}\n> ${sunday[2].summary}`})
        }
```

So as you can see, I check if the length of sunday is whatever it is (aka how many items in the array) if its 1 or > 1 keep adding "\n> ${sunday[1].summary}" (info from another array. the [1] would also need to increase as it needs to select the next array object) to the string depending on the length. This is fine but not so clean, and its hard coded so if the array has more than 3, then it would most likely break.
If anyone can help me with a cleaner more efficient way of doing this that would be awesome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would `map` the day to the summary, then join each value with a newline:

```
const summary = sunday.length == 0 
    ? '> Nothing'
    : sunday.map(day => `> ${day.summary}`).join('\n');

Embed.addFields({name: 'Sunday', value: summary})
```

Comment: Ahhh perfect, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is there no for loop or while loop?
If there is a while loop, create a variable and subtract 1 from it until it hits 0.
I'm not sure the language, or I would write it here for you.

maybe...

```
if (sunday.length == 0) {
    Embed.addFields({name: 'Sunday', value: `> Nothing`})
}
else {
    var text = ""
    for (int i = 0; i < ; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            text = text + sunday[i].summary;
        else {
            text = text + "\n" + sunday[i].summary;
        }
    }
}
```